# Display Events in Fullcalendar underneath calendar?

Tags: coldfusion, fullcalendar, mura

I am having a hard time to do this. The calendar Displays the events in the calendar however, I would like to be able to list the events as well below the calendar so you can see the full name of the events that are in the current month. I have the following code(I am using coldfusion and Mura and I am new to both):

```
<cffunction name="MultipleFeaturedEvents">
    <cfargument name="feedName" type="string" default="702771E7-155D-0201-11DF8865B175735F"/>
    <cfargument name="maxMonths" type="numeric" default="3" />
    <cfargument name="groupDailyEvents" default="true" />
        <cfscript>

            var rs = '';
            var subRS1 = '';
            var local = {};
            local.listIDs = '';

            local.util = $.getCalendarUtility();
            local.rsItems = local.util.getCalendarItems(calendarid=arguments.feedName, start=Now(), end=DateAdd('m', val(4), Now()));


            var qoq = new Query();
            qoq.setDBType('query');
            qoq.setAttributes(rs=local.rsItems, maxRows=val(1));
            qoq.setSQL('
                SELECT *
                FROM rs
                ORDER BY displaystart ASC
            ');
            var qoqResult = qoq.execute().getResult();
            local.it = $.getBean('contentIterator').setQuery(qoqResult);

        </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>
                <cfset ctr=1 />
                <!---<div>#local.it.hasNext()#</div>--->
                <cfloop condition="(local.it.hasNext()) AND (ctr LT 4)">
                    <cfset local.item = local.it.next() >
                    <cfif not ListFind(local.listIDs, local.item.getValue('contentid'))>
                        <cfif ctr eq 1>
                            <!--- TODO: set a default image if no image is available --->
                            <div class="hidden-xs col-md-2">
                                <p class="upcoming-events-image"><img src="#local.item.getImageURL()#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#"> </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-4" id="featured-event">
                                <h3>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getMenuTitle())#</h3>
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar fixIconCal"></i>
                                <!---#local.item.getDisplaystart()#--->
                                #LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'), "mmm d, yyyy")#
                                <cfquery dbtype="query" name="subRS1">
                                    select *
                                    from rsItems
                                    where rsItems.contentid = <cfqueryparam value="#local.item.getValue('contentid')#" />
                                </cfquery>
                                <cfif subRS1.recordcount gt 1>
                                    <!--- end date --->
                                    <cfset enddate = ListLast(ValueList(subRS1.displaystop)) />
                                    <cfif IsValid('date', enddate)>
                                        - #LSDateFormat(enddate)#
                                    </cfif>
                                </cfif>
                                <br />
                                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                #timeFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'), "h:mm tt")# - #timeFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStop'), "h:mm tt")#
                                <br />
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                Location Information
                                <!--- Summary --->
                                <div class="featured-event-summary">
                                    <cfif Len(local.item.getValue('summary'))>
                                    #local.item.getValue('summary')#
                                    </cfif>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <cfelse>
                        </cfif>
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

Below is what I am trying to do:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can use plain JS (I don't know ColdFusion), but typically you can retrieve all FullCalendar events by invoking:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents')
```

Which returns array of Events, then you can iterate over it and render some list.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

So maybe something like

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
     //will loop for each event you have in the calendar
     console.log(ev); //event
});
```

And you can use something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
     $('.your-list-container').append('<div>' + ev.title + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: @Kryzstar: Above, I have attached a image on what I am trying to do and I am still learning

Comment: Please look at my example, I think that you can render your list in that loop, so you would read title, start date, end date, etc...and put them inside some divs, containers, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to render this list by using the ColdFusion template(?) so not by reading events from the calendar (you have all the data from DB query, maybe just repeat code which reads the data for the calendar?), but unfortunately I can't help.

Comment: I have tried that but did not work, I will try your way and see if it works. The code, guessing I would do that in the function corect? or somehwere else

Answer (score 0):

```
   this is js code , hope its help you ..
   //get the start and the end of the current view

    var startDate = $('#idOfCalendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
    var endDate = $('#idOfCalendar').fullCalendar('getView').end;
    var eventsNames= new Array();


    var todaysEvents = $('#idOfCalendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
        if (event.start >= startDate && event.start <= endDate 
            || event.end >= startDate && event.end <= endDate) {

                eventsNames.push(event.title) 
                //take what do you whant from the event object 

                return true;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Guessing I would keep the script I have above, and remove what I have in the cfoutput and add your code, add the events  and so on correct? Sorry really new to all this and it took me a while to do the code above